# Manually Binding A RadGrid with non-standard date format?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik-grid

I attempting to manually bind a radgrid to a view. The issue is I need to query by dates and sort by dates, however the original developer stores the dates as strings in the DB and with a non-standard format of "yyyyMMdd"

Is there a way to automatically bind it, or do i have to do a manual bind? If i have to do it manually what is the best way to do this? Read the view into a datatable? Re-Cast all of the dates, and then bind the datatable to the grid?

Answer (score 0):

In the `NeedDataSource` event use a `LINQ` selector to get the values and convert the date stored in the database to a `TimeStamp`.

Alternatively you can modify the given column to have a `TimeStamp` value in the database (make sure you are using a transaction, not allow writes to that table and save all the values temporarily somewhere so you can load them back, maybe into a temporary table having the id and the date).